# Run application within windows service

Tags: python, windows-services, subprocess, stdout, popen

I have simple windows service in python and I need to run some external application for example notepad.exe. When I try to launch this application within windows services, so nothig happens. However when I open list of process in my Windows Task Manager, I can see there the notepad.exe. 
My code for launching the notepad.exe:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('"C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"', shell=True, bufsize=128,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you created the service, did you allow it to interact with the desktop?

Comment: Thank you for answer. No I didn´t. So I did it and suddenly  Interactive Services Detection was viewed. I have never seen it. But I don´t want some special interface I would like the notepad was launched normaly.